# Fluid columns with one max-width column

Tags: css, fluid

I am trying to make a two column layout where:

1st Col: Has a maximum width of say 200px
2nd Col: Fills up the remaining space

I have tried a few examples but haven't been able to achieve the desired effect.

As the 1st column isn't going to be a fixed width, positioning that absolutely and adding a left margin to the 2nd column leaves empty spacing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with the code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) which is already well supported by modern browsers.

Quick overview: http://learnlayout.com/flexbox.html
More detailed: https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties

Or maybe if your use case is very simple you could use just `calc` function in CSS. For example:

```
#first {
    width: 200px;
}

#second {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **Flexbox**

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="col"><strong>Col 1</strong><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur odit necessitatibus illum officiis. Qui fugiat quisquam sequi, vel maxime earum id, officiis labore itaque debitis dolor laboriosam ipsam, dignissimos ullam. </div>
  <div class="col"><strong>Col 2</strong></div>
</div>
```